# Check of the Majorana condition in Srednicki's book

Tags: conventions, spinors, majorana-fermions, charge-conjugation

I wonder how it is possible to reach at the equation (37.18) also called the Majorana condition:

$$\bar{\Psi} = \Psi^T {\cal{C}}\tag{37.18} $$

of Srednicki's book from (37.16), (37.17) and (37.19).

We have

$$\Psi =\left( \begin{array}{c} \psi_c \\ \psi^{\dagger\dot{c}} \end{array}\right)\tag{37.16}$$

and $$\bar{\Psi} = (\psi^a, \psi^\dagger_\dot{a})\tag{37.17}$$  and $\Psi^T = (\psi_c,  \psi^{\dagger\dot{c}})$.

With the definition of the charge conjugation matrix:

$${\cal{C}}=\left( \begin{array}{cc} -\epsilon^{ac} & 0 \\ 0 & -\epsilon_{\dot{a}\dot{c}} \end{array}\right).\tag{37.19}$$

If we compute $\Psi^T {\cal{C}}$ we get:

$$\Psi^T {\cal{C}} = ( - \psi_c \epsilon^{ac} , -\psi^{\dagger\dot{c}}\epsilon_{\dot{a}\dot{c}} )$$

According to Srednicki (34.26) we have $\psi^a = -\psi_b\epsilon^{ba}$ or $\psi^a = \psi_b\epsilon^{ab}$. Furthermore applying what Srednicki says at the beginning of page 213 about dotted notation eq. (34.25) $$\psi_a = \epsilon_{ab}\psi^b\tag{34.25}$$ is also valid for dotted indices: $\psi^\dagger_\dot{a} = \epsilon_{\dot{a}\dot{b}} \psi^{\dagger\dot{b}}$. I assume that I can commute $\epsilon$ with $\psi$ without generating a minus sign we finally get:

$$\Psi^T {\cal{C}} = ( - \psi_c \epsilon^{ac} , -\psi^{\dagger\dot{c}}\epsilon_{\dot{a}\dot{c}} )= (-\psi^a,-\psi^\dagger_{\dot{a}}) = -\bar{\Psi}$$

which is wrong by a minus sign with respect to the Majorana condition. Where is the sign error? This is not a homework assignment. I cannot imagine that Srednicki made such an error in so closely following formulas. Which spinor algebra rule did I overlook?

Comment: The index structure in (37.19) assumes the spinor to the *right* of $\mathcal{C}$ will be the one with $c, \dot{c}$ indices.

Comment: @ConnorBehan you mean I should choose $\Psi^T =(\psi_a, \psi^{\dagger\dot{a}})$ ?

Comment: Yes. And $\bar{\Psi}$ would have the $c$'s.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you very much. That was very helpful.